# Can someone identify these cable connectors?

Tags: connector, identification, cables

The cable that i have attached in the pictures below need to be replaced. I don't know the names(types) of the two connectors so i need your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

The device i need to connect:

[image]

Comment: Besides the terms provided in the existing answer, the term Insulation Displacement Connector might yield suitable results in a search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are a 1x4 latched (and keyed) dupont connector and a 2x7 (Keyed) IDC connector respectively.

Comment: The first picture is a bit blurry, but if you look at the full sized version, you can clearly see that the dupont connector has two key slots on the other side.

Comment: So it does. I must be getting old.

Comment: Actually, is keyed the right term? Orientation slots/tabs? Hmm.

Comment: "Keyed" is acceptably short for "Polarizing Key", IMHO.

Comment: Because I was just looking it up. Samtec calls the above Notch Polarization. They also have Position Polarization where a hole in the IDC connector is not opened, and Key Polarization, which is a plastic pin that can optionally be inserted. @dextorb

Comment: I have put 3 more photos. When i search for dupont connectors i think is not like the one i want. I want to connect one makerbot mechanical endstop like the picture.

Comment: Ignacio, can you share some links for dupont connectors? Is it a manufacturer specific line?

Comment: @HL-SDK: It's not manufacturer-specific per se, but most don't have a name for it, e.g. Harwin's M20 housings (although those don't have latches or keys).

Answer (score 2):

It's maybe late for you, but could be helpful for others. Latched/keyed/buckled/secured etc... are to vague. Funny when I googled images with MOLEX 2520 I got plenty of results especially for this connector.But that probably is more coincidence.

If you will google 
"SL Crimp Housing, Single Row, Version G, Positive Latch, 4 Circuits" you will get to molex website. Exact part number it's Molex 70066G (the G version is the polarity keyed + latch/buckle).

http://datasheet.octopart.com/50-57-9404-Molex-datasheet-78853.pdf

The "Positive Latch" is term used by molex. You can see this connector and few similar in this catalog (search inside the PDF for 70066G):

http://www.molex.com/catalog/web_catalog/pdfs/C.pdf

On page 3 it's on the bottom of the illustration. I'm going into these extends to describe it, because if you will use Latched dupont. Somewhere they dupont is not metioned, just the 2.54 female connector etc... But this way you should be able to find more stores having this (maybe just under different name).